# Are solid fuel rocket engines designed differently and how?

Tags: engine-design, rocket

How do solid fuel (Hydrazine, UDMH) and oxidizer (N2O4) differ in design from cryogenic rocket engines such as LH2 and LOX?
Are there differences related to temperature, material design, turbopumps, turbopump bearing seals, etc?

Comment: This belongs to space.stackexchamge.com.

Comment: Hydrazine, UDMH and N2O4 are liquid propellants, not solid.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, solid fuel rockets are **very** different from liquid fueled rockets. A solid fuel rocket is basically some solidified rocket fuel and oxidizer wrapped in a non-combustible cylinder (hence the name). Once it's lit, there's no way to throttle it or shut it down, it just burns until all the fuel is consumed. On the other hand, in a liquid fuel rocket (cryogenic or not), liquid fuel and oxidizer are pumped into a combustion chamber to be burned. Liquid fuel rockets can be throttled or shut down by controlling the fuel pumps, and can be re-lit once shut down (assuming its igniter is reusable).

(It's important to note that the examples of "solid" rocket fuels you gave aren't actually solids. They're liquids, just like cryogenic fuels are. A solid fuel would be something like the ammonium perchlorate and aluminum powder used in the [Space Shuttle Solid Rocket Boosters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_Shuttle_Solid_Rocket_Booster).)

Comment: small addition: it's theoretically possible to have a solid fuel engine that can be throttled. Not sure if it's ever been done, but envision an engine where solid fuels in powder form are fed into a combustion chamber (though at the pressures needed you could probably treat them as liquids in calculations).